# Problem installing wine

Tags: apt, 20.04, wine

```
ozil@ozil-Vostro-3500:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~impish-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Is it really Impish (21.10)?

Comment: no 20.04.03    but

Comment: sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~impish-1)

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: i am install wine ubuntu 20.04.03

Comment: Please [edit] your question; and show `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score -4):

You must install `wine-stable` first. Tutorials of how to do this can be found online. After it is installed, run `sudo apt update` and install WineHQ.

Comment: My 20.04 wine installation doesn't have wine-stable or wine-hq in it.